# How to determine Translation and Rotation Matrix using openCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, stereo-3d

I have two images taken from a stereo camera.How can I find Translation and Rotation Matrix using OpenCv ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calibrate your cameras by using the function below. It will give you the translation and rotation matrices:

```
cv::stereoCalibrate()
```

More information [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/calib3d_camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereocalibrate)